# Flash happening using React-beautiful-dnd and Cloud Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-beautiful-dnd

I am developing a react-application that uses Firebase(Cloud Firestore), Redux and React-beautiful-DnD.

[Here is gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WDbS.gif)

Whenever I move ToDo-Task to another column, a flash happening.
I assume the reasons are for calling multiple requests to Cloud Firestore at once. 
Here is the code I use to request update()  to Cloud Firestore.

Note: I used "transaction" though, I'm not willing to use it because the processing takes a long time to catch the data from Cloud Functions. Also used "batch" though, a flash happened likewise.

---

```
  export const UpdateColumn = (newState, drraggableId) => {
  console.log(newState, drraggableId);
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();

    const taskId = drraggableId;
    const startColumnName = Object.keys(newState.newStart);
    const finishColumnName = Object.keys(newState.newFinish);


    firestore
      .collection("columns")
      .doc(startColumnName[0].toString())
      .update({
        taskIds: newState.newStart[startColumnName].taskIds
      });

    firestore
      .collection("columns")
      .doc(finishColumnName[0].toString())
      .update({
        taskIds: newState.newFinish[finishColumnName].taskIds
      });

    firestore
      .collection("projects")
      .doc(taskId)
      .update({
        currentColumn: finishColumnName[0]
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_COLUMN_SUCCESS" });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_COLUMN_ERROR", err });
      });
  };
};
```

Following are the dependencies I am using in the project:

```
"firebase": "^7.6.1",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-beautiful-dnd": "^12.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-redux": "^5.1.1",
"react-redux-firebase": "^2.2.4",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.3.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-firestore": "^0.11.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

I have the same problem. I have an aweful lot of re-renders. Could this be your problem too?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a similar problem. This can be happening because the call to Firebase is asynchronous, so there is a bit of a delay before your `then` is been executed. And RBD requires that the effect `onDragEnd` be synchronous.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/responders.md#life-cycle-%EF%B8%8F):

> onDragEnd (required): A drag has ended. It is the responsibility of this responder to synchronously apply changes that has resulted from the drag

The solution would be to uptade your state by hand before calling Firebase.

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it's as smooth as butter now.